# Time difference in Iso8601 formate

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to calculate the difference between two times and I need to send data to data base in this formate `"P3Y6M4DT12H30M17S"`
I am using `.difference` method and get difference.

**Code:**

```
 final birthday = DateTime(1977, 5, 22);
 final birthday1 = DateTime(1967, 10, 12);
 final difference = birthday.difference(birthday1);
 print(difference.toIso8601String()); //error line
```

**Problem:**

```
The method 'toIso8601String' isn't defined for the type 'Duration'.
```

How I can save time difference in `Iso8601String`.

Comment: The problem is difference is not in Time format, it's in only days. So, you can't convert days to toIso8601String as per [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/toIso8601String.html)

Comment: then, what is the possibility to get a time difference and save in this format?

Comment: It's not possible to convert a `Duration` object (which stores just a number of microseconds) by itself to an ISO-8601 duration format because that format is ambiguous without knowing the starting or ending times.  For example, "P1M" could mean 28, 29, 30, or 31 days.  You would need to write a function that generates the ISO-8601 duration string from the start and end `DateTime` objects and that internally does its own calculations instead of using `DateTime.difference`.

Comment: Alternatively, if generating a string such as "P365D" is acceptable instead of, say, "P1Y" (apparently this is not specified by the standard), then formatting a `Duration` object would be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Generating a time difference greater than a month is a non-trivial task because the number of days in a month is not constant. For example, the difference between `Jan 1` and `Mar 1 ` and the difference between `Jul 1` and `Sept 1` are both two months, even though *in days* the difference is 59 days and 62 days, respectively. If you want to deal with *years*, it gets even more complicated since you have to take leap years and [date anomalies](https://www.britannica.com/story/ten-days-that-vanished-the-switch-to-the-gregorian-calendar) into account. And that's not even mentioning time zones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ISO-8601 duration strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) aren't something to be taken lightly for the reasons I stated in my comment. However, there's the simple version and the "correct" version.

### Simple version

Strictly speaking, the ISO-8601 standard doesn't require that it's components include the "correct" number in each value position, so you could just as well use arbitrarily large numbers for the day value and call it good. However, you will be at the mercy of whatever system you send these strings to as far as whether it will accept them. But if you are dealing in durations that rarely go for longer than a day, or if you're using a context that doesn't care about the ability to deconstruct the duration (such as a cron pattern), this approach should be sufficient.

```dart
void main() {
  final birthday = DateTime(1977, 5, 22);
  final birthday1 = DateTime(1967, 10, 12);
  final difference = birthday.difference(birthday1);
  print(difference.toIso8601String()); // P3510DT0H0M0S
}

extension IsoDuration on Duration {
  static const _hoursInDays = 24;
  static const _minutesInHours = 60;
  static const _secondsInMinutes = 60;
  static const _millisInSeconds = 1000;
  
  String toIso8601String() {
    final days = this.inDays.toInt();
    final hours = (this.inHours % _hoursInDays).toInt();
    final minutes = (this.inMinutes % _minutesInHours).toInt();
    final seconds = (this.inSeconds % _secondsInMinutes);
    return 'P${days}DT${hours}H${minutes}M${seconds}S';
  }
}
```

### "Correct" Version

Again, duration strings in practice aren't so easy. You need to take into account like number of days in the months spanned by the duration, leap years, leap *seconds*, time zones, and just random things that affect otherwise normal dates. (There's a reason big complex libraries like `moment` and `luxon` exist in the JavaScript world.)

Instead of a regular duration string, the recommendation is to do an [interval string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) which is comprised of both the timestamp for the starting time **and** the duration stamp. That way something like `P3M` can make sense if it's given in the context of `2020-01-05T12:00:00/P3M`. (The three months in that case can be figured out to mean 91 days since it involves January, February, and March during a leap year.)

There isn't really a "simple" solution for this. The brute force method would be to manually count the years between the start and end time followed by the months, and then use the normal duration difference for the remainder. (Of course, this is assuming that Dart's `DateTime` class takes all the aforementioned problems into account.)

```dart
void main() {
  final birthday = DateTime(1977, 5, 22);
  final birthday1 = DateTime(1967, 10, 12);
  final interval = Interval.fromDates(birthday, birthday1);
  print(interval.toIso8601String()); // 1967-10-12T00:00:00.000/P9Y7M10DT0H0M0S
}

class Interval {
  final DateTime start;
  final int years;
  final int months;
  final int days;
  final int hours;
  final int minutes;
  final double seconds;
  
  const Interval(
    this.start,
    this.years,
    this.months,
    this.days,
    this.hours,
    this.minutes,
    this.seconds,
  );
  
  const Interval.zero(DateTime start) : this(start, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  
  factory Interval.fromDates(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    if (start.isAtSameMomentAs(end)) return Interval.zero(start);
    if (start.isAfter(end)) {
      final temp = start;
      start = end;
      end = temp;
    }
    
    int years = 0;
    int months = 0;
    var marker = start;
    
    while (_addYear(marker).isBefore(end)) {
      marker = _addYear(marker);
      years++;
    }
    
    while (_addMonth(marker).isBefore(end)) {
      marker = _addMonth(marker);
      months++;
    }
    
    final diff = marker.difference(end).abs();
    final days = diff.inDays;
    final hours = diff.inHours % _hoursInDays;
    final minutes = diff.inMinutes % _minutesInHours;
    final seconds = (diff.inMicroseconds % _microsInSeconds) / 1000000;
    
    return Interval(start, years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds);
  }
  
  static const _hoursInDays = 24;
  static const _minutesInHours = 60;
  static const _secondsInMinutes = 60;
  static const _microsInSeconds = 1000000;
  
  static DateTime _addYear(DateTime dt) {
    return DateTime(dt.year + 1, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second, dt.millisecond, dt.microsecond);
  }
  
  static DateTime _addMonth(DateTime dt) {
    return DateTime(dt.year, dt.month + 1, dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second, dt.millisecond, dt.microsecond);
  }
  
  String toIso8601String() {
    return '${start.toIso8601String()}/P${years}Y${months}M${days}DT${hours}H${minutes}M${seconds}S';
  }
}
```

A more elegant solution would likely involve a moment-like library in its own right.